# Temperature problem in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ati, 14.04, overheating, vga

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (dual booting with windows 8.1) in my Dell Inspiron n7520, which comes with a dedicated VGA AMD Radeon HD7730M.

There had occurred some heating problems in Ubuntu, so I installed `TLP` and some additional application that shows frequency of the processor, that shows solved the problem, but when i tried `sensors` command in terminal it shows that CPU temperature is [OK] (between the limits). but temperature of VGA is too high (current temp as +511°C and critical level is +120°C).

What should I do for fixing the above problem? --Please help!

Comment: Are you sure the sensors are OK? 511 degress is not normal temperature (there must be smoke and maybe light).

Comment: yeah i also thought about it.but it show like that

Comment: That's a bug. There is no way your GPU is running at 511 degrees. That would have melted your computer and the table it's sitting on and would have started burning through the floor. Please [edit] your question and include the output of `sensors` and also `sensors-detect`.

Comment: here are the outputs    http://postimg.org/gallery/3jghw3uuc/

Comment: Please don't post _images_ of text. Just copy the text from your terminal and paste it into your question. You can use the formatting tricks explained [here](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to make it look good. Anyway, did you load the `coretemp` module as suggested? If not, do so with `sudo modprobe coretemp` and run `sensors` again. In any case, the output you get is irrelevant. The 511 is just a bug so unless your laptop _feels_ hot, ignore it.